# I'm not able to connect to internet on Android Emulator, I'm using Tata Photon+(2g Mobile Broadband) device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-internet

I'm not able to connect to internet on Android Emulator, I'm using Tata Photon+ device.

I've disabled my all other connection like Lan and Wifi...
Removed all other settings like other mobile, and other device dial-up settings.

Please help me, how to connect to internet using android emulator.

My Emulator shows the 3g and signal icons correctly, there is no cross mark on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because the emulator is not able to resolve the DNS

1. Either start the emulator from command prompt like this - 
   $:\Android\tools>emulator -avd  **-dns-server 8.8.8.8** 
   You should see a message like this - ***DNS server name '8.8.8.8' resolved to 8.8.8.8:55***

OR

1. In eclipse Run Configuration -> Select your application from LHS -> Targets tab on RHS -> Additional command line options textbox give **-dns-server 8.8.8.8**

Comment: Okay I'll try this. Actually I've installed ccproxy in my system, and when I do proxy setting on my emulator its getting connected. But the problem is every day I've to get my new IP and make the proxy setting. Thanks for your response, I'll try your suggestion.